# Bundle works wrong for css

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, bundle

I have these css files included in layout

```
<!-- Dropdown Menu -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/superfish.css">
<!-- Date Picker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
<!-- CS Select -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/cs-select.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/cs-skin-border.css">
<!-- Themify Icons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/themify-icons.css">
<!-- Flat Icon -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/flaticon.css">
<!-- Icomoon -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/icomoon.css">
<!-- Flexslider  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/flexslider.css">
<!-- Style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/style.css">
```

now I want to move these files in `bundle` so I did that:

```
public static void RegisterBundler(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/style.css").Include(
            "~/Content/superfish.css",
            "~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css",
            "~/Content/cs-select.css",
            "~/Content/cs-skin-border.css",
            "~/Content/themify-icons.css",
            "~/Content/flaticon.css",
            "~/Content/icomoon.css",
            "~/Content/flexslider.css",
            "~/Content/style.css"
            ));

        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
    }
```

and in my layout:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/style.css")
```

but from this:

[image]

it goes to this:

[image]

some of `css` code is missing when i open this new css file (from browser developer tool). Especially whole first file is missing (`superfish.css`) but it is in the same folder as others

What did I wrong?

Comment: @Morpheus you should post that as answer. it works

Comment: posted as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might get confused and renders the actual `style.css` instead of the bundle. Try changing the name of the bundle to something else, i.e. new `StyleBundle("~/Content/main.css")`. Also, you probably using the render wrong - it should be `@Styles.Render("~/Content/style")` (note the removed `.css` part)

Answer (score 1):

Bundling is a new feature in ASP.NET 4.5 that makes it easy to combine or bundle multiple files into a single file.

The Bundle class Include method takes an array of strings, where each string is a virtual path to resource.

**Change your code like below:**

**Note :** remove the file extension inside the StyleBundle()

```
public static void RegisterBundler(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
       //

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/style").Include(
            "~/Content/superfish.css",
            "~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css",
            "~/Content/cs-select.css",
            "~/Content/cs-skin-border.css",
            "~/Content/themify-icons.css",
            "~/Content/flaticon.css",
            "~/Content/icomoon.css",
            "~/Content/flexslider.css",
            "~/Content/style.css"
            ));

        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
    }
```

**In Layout:** Call like below

@Styles.Render("~/Content/style")

Hope it was helpful